# Parsing array inside a JSON response

Tags: json, angularjs, angular

So I'm working on REST API which is being consumed in angular and getting the response in the following format

I'm getting the short description but when I try to display that using *ngfor it's not working I'm an absolute beginner in angular so any guidance will be helpful thank you

````
{
    "data": {
        "Query": "sample query",
        "numbers": [
            "0013290",
            "160011736",
            "130004057",
            "2075333",
            "0015416"
        ],
        "Scores": [
            94.66,
            94.48,
            78.12,
            0.17,
            0.15
        ],
        "Short_descriptions": [
            "sample 1",
            "sample 1",
            "sample 1",
            "sample 1",
            "sample 1"
        ],
       
    }
}


 this.query='{ "query": "sample query" }';
    this.homeService.getTop5KbArticles(this.query).subscribe(data => {
    this.KBdata =data["data"];
     this.shortDesc =this.KBdata["Short_descriptions"]

<div class="col-md-5" *ngFor="let x of shortDesc">
<p>{{x.Short_descriptions}}</p>
</div>

```
````

Comment: change <p>{{x.Short_descriptions}}</p> to <p>{{x}}</p>

Comment: if i understood your question correctly, you want backward-compatibility? JSON.stringify, so like this  var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yourArray);

Comment: @Nonik thanks that worked

Comment: Sorry for the confusion as I said I'm a absolute beginner ,let me rephrase it what if i want to use other fields like scores and numbers with short descriptions in ngfor

Comment: then your data is wrong.  seems you data is set of arrays, you first need to map your data into correct format, then pass it to your view, seems you need something like this [{Short_description:"sample 1", Score:94.66, number:"0013290" }]

Comment: exactly how would i go about doing that ,any suggestions ?

Comment: use map method of array https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank you will try that

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{{x.Short_descriptions}}` with `{{x}}`.

When you writes `*ngFor="let x of shortDesc"`, it means that `x` will be an item of `shortDesc` which is an array of simple strings.

Comment: Understood ,what if i want to use other fields like scores and numbers with short descriptions in ngfor

Comment: You can change your `ngFor` to expose the index `ngFor="let x of shortDesc, let index as I"` and reuse the `i` like `KBData.scores[i]`. Or change your data structure to create an array of objects.

Comment: getting the following error when i do that Can't bind to 'ngForAs' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description

Comment: Made a small typo in my previous comment: `ngFor="let x of shortDesc; index as i"`